# How to enable Kubernetes default resource quota for all namespaces?

Tags: kubernetes, quota

I know Kubernetes manage resource quota on namespace level by `kubectl create quota --namespace=xxx`. But it needs manual work each time there is a new namespaces created.

My question is, is there a way to set up a cluster level default resource quota which can apply to all namespaces automatically?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to set up quota for all namespaces by default. Please file a feature request and describe your use case.